# `in` keyword vs inner `join` which one is better for performance?

Tags: sql, performance, join, inner-join

I have the following query

```
select roles.roleId from roles where roles.roleId in (select userRoles.roleId from userRoles where userRoles.userId=10)
```

which could be done also like this

```
 select roles.roleId from roles, userRoles where roles.roleId = userRoles.roleId and userRoles.userId = 10;
```

so which one is better for performance to use the `inner join` or to use `in` keyword

Comment: You missed to join in the second query

Comment: @juergend thanks for alerting